# Issue with Log in to Parse.com using Facebook credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I created a Facebook account, set up Parse.com app and developed iOS application as suggested by Parse.com website. I followed all the steps to make changes in info.plist file and in app delegate class.
Below is my code and I tried to debug it line by line. I noticed that FB asks for user permission and even after accepting it, no further action takes place.

```
- (IBAction)fblogin:(FBSDKLoginButton *)sender {

    NSArray *permissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];

    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertVeiw = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alertVeiw show];
        } else {

            [self loadData];
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        }
    }];

}

-(void)loadData{

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email, public_profile"}];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             // NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;

//             NSString *first = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
//             NSString *last = [result objectForKey:@"last_name"];
//             NSString *username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", first, last];
             NSString *name = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
             NSString *email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];

             PFUser *userFb = [PFUser currentUser];

             [userFb setObject:name forKey:@"username"];
             [userFb setObject:email forKey:@"email"];
             [userFb saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                 if (error)
                 {
                     UIAlertView *alertVeiw = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

                     [alertVeiw show];
                 } else {

                     [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] setObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"userId"];
                     [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];
                     //   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                 }
             }];
         }

     }];
}
```

I couldn't understand why is it not working.

Imported frameworks into .m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import "InboxViewController.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
```

above is the only login code i have and im not sure why its not working. When i first added and changed the code it would log in and provide a random username. Then when i kept trying different methods and finally ended up with method above it stopped logging in

Comment: Show me what relevant framework you imported in m file. How's your config in h file? What've you done to debug? What's the difference to another question you created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537554/login-user-through-facebook-ios-parse-com?rq=1 ?

Comment: @SanitLee see above question

Comment: I'm still not sure what you've been debugging exactly but I understand it may be quite a mess to get it working. One thing I'd like to see is what you've set in your app delegate. You may need some Facebook login initialised there, so just show me this method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Comment: @SanitLee i have these 2 methods in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` they are `[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];` and
   
  `[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];`

Comment: Well @Joey121 I've never used FBSDKLoginKit so I can't comment much on that but if you don't mind using ParseFacebookUtils I think I can help. If so, I can edit my answer in your previous question to show my config in app delegate.

Comment: @SanitLee yes please i am using parse.com also as a backend and also for facebook login

Comment: OK @Joey121 so please go back to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537554/login-user-through-facebook-ios-parse-com/34575637#34575637 to see my improved answer which shows my config regarding Facebook login in my app delegate

Comment: Be sure that you don't mix up my solution with yours - that way will only add more complexity. By my way, first off you have to create login button and link action to it.

Comment: Have you followed my settings in app delegate which I just added?

Comment: @SanitLee when i import parseUtilsFramework i get error saying facebookSDK.h not found so in latest version we use v4 and also we have to add FBSDK

Comment: There is FacebookSDK framework so just import that into your project.